# Can't insert data to db in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I just learn RoR and confuse now how to insert data to db. Here's my code:

**book_insert.html.erb**

```
<%= content_for :helloworld do %>
    <%= form_tag("/insert", method: "post") do %>
        <%= label_tag(:title, "Title") %>
        <%= text_field_tag(:title) %><br>
        <%= label_tag(:price, "Price") %>
        <%= number_field_tag(:price) %><br>
        <%= label_tag(:subject_id, "Subject ID") %>
        <%= number_field_tag(:subject_id) %><br>
        <%= label_tag(:description, "Description") %>
        <%= text_field_tag(:description) %><br>
        <br>
        <%= submit_tag("Submit") %> 
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

**book_controller.rb**

```
class BookController < ApplicationController
    def insert
        @book = Book.new(book_params)
        @book.save
        render :book_page
    end

    def book_params
        params.require(:books).permit(:title, :price, :subject_id, :description)
    end

    def showinsert
        render :book_insert
    end
end
```

It returns error:

> Completed 400 Bad Request in 4ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
>   ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is
>   empty: books):

Please help. Thanks

Comment: What tutorial or book to you follow? I am asking because it is quite uncommon to build forms manually with the `tag` helpers. Usually, you would use Rails form helpers to build forms (see the [Rails Guide about this topic](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#binding-a-form-to-an-object))  - especially because these helpers provide the default nesting that you try to use in the `book_params` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`form_tag`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/form_tag) normally used to submit **non-model** actions to the mapped `controller#action`. You probably need to use [`form_for`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/form_for) and its *corresponding helpers* inside the form

```
<%= content_for :helloworld do %>
  <%= form_for Book.new, url: "/insert", method: "post" do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :title %>
    <%= f.text_field :title %><br>
    <%= f.label :price %>
    <%= f.number_field :price %><br>
    <%= f.label :subject_id %>
    <%= f.number_field :subject_id %><br>
    <%= f.label :description %>
    <%= f.text_field :description %><br>
    <br>
    <%= f.submit "Submit" %> 
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

With the above code, the `params` would be passed inside `:book => {}` hash, so you need to change the `book_params` to below

```
def book_params
  params.require(:book).permit(:title, :price, :subject_id, :description)
end              #^
```

Comment: But now why the data is not inserted to db? Please look at my insert method

Comment: @HendroFebrian What does the log say? Did you get any error in the log?

Comment: @HendroFebrian Ok there is a  **ROLLBACK** which probably due to any validations that are failing. Can you update the question with the code for `Book` model?

Comment: Oh it was my bad. It  works now. Thank you so much Pavan.

Comment: @HendroFebrian I suggest you to use @max approach of using resourceful routes and conventions for naming method names and corresponding view pages. What you are doing is a simple *Create* as in **CRUD(Create, Read, Update, Delete)** so normally the method would say just `create` and the action that renders the form would be just `new` and its view page as `new.html.erb`

Comment: Ok. I wanna ask one more question Pavan. Is it needed in RoR to do both define table association in db migration and define association in model class? Or just go with one of them?

Comment: @HendroFebrian It is not simple to answer your question and for you to understand. I recommend you to read [*active_record_basics*](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html), [*active_record_migrations*](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html) and [*active_record_associations*](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) in the same order to understand what is *ApplicationRecord(alias for ActiveRecord)* and what it does under the hood. That way you will know the answer for your question.

Answer (score 2):

The `params.require` method requires that the key `books` is present in the hash - if not it raises an `ActionController::ParameterMissing` exception.

To nest inputs you need to name them accordingly:

```
<%= form_tag("/insert", method: "post") do %>
  <%= label_tag("Title") %>
  <%= text_field_tag("books[title]") %><br>
  <%= label_tag("Price") %>
  <%= number_field_tag("books[price]") %
  ...
  <%= submit_tag("Submit") %> 
<% end %>
```

This will give the params hash:

```
{ books: { title: 'Life & Times of Michael K', price: 99 } }
```

However thats pretty tedious. A better way is to use the forms helpers and setup your routes and controller according to the conventions:

```
# config/routes.rb
resources :books

# app/views/books/new.html.erb
<%= form_for(@book) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>
  # ...
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>

# app/controllers/books_controller.rb
class BooksController < ApplicationController
  # this renders the form to create a new book
  # GET /books/new
  def new
    @book = Book.new
  end

  # In Rails its called create - not insert
  # POST /books
  def create
    @book = Book.new(book_params)
    if @book.save
      redirect_to @book
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  # This is the path to show a book
  # its also where we redirect after creating the book
  # GET /books/:id
  def show
    @book = Book.find(params[:id])
  end

  # ...

  private 
    def book_params
      # note thats its book singular - not plural
      params.require(:book).permit(:title, :price, :subject_id, :description)
    end
end
```

Comment: I would really recommend you try something like https://www.railstutorial.org/ as 99% of learning rails is learning the rails conventions (also known as the Rails Way). Its not really a framework where you can figure everything out for yourself and be productive or even write acceptable code.

Answer (score -1):

You should do `book` in the `book_params` method instead of `books`:

```
def book_params
    params.require(:book).permit(:title, :price, :subject_id, :description)
end
```

Comment: The OP didn't use the Rails form helpers, therefore, the params aren't nested.

Comment: you're correct, I missed that part! My eye caught only the part inside `book_params` @spickermann